# WebDriver not teching changed text of an Element

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am using POM framework with `PageFactory.InitElements()`. When I identify a Element using

```
 @FindBy(xpath="//span[@data-default-label='Price from']") 
WebElement priceFromTextField;
```

Whose HTML looks like:

```html
`
<a class="button button-from numeric gray block fnormal rel zi3 clr" href="javascript:void(0);">
  <span class="header block" data-default-label="Price from">Price from</span>
  <span class="icon abs down" />
</a>`
```

and used to enter a text into the text field. When I again tried to use it for Comparison , priceFrom.getText() is returning null always. After entering the text into textfield the text PriceFrom is replaced by String value given by me. But when i want to fetch this for Comparison its returning null. Any answers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try fetching the text from the element before typing into it? Usually the text box will be an input,textarea,text tag

Comment: Problem solved by using explicit wait. Thanks alot for ur reply Sudharsan!!!